# How do Mathematicians send email?

Tags: soft-question

I've been corresponding with people about math via email. It seems very weird to just be sending PDFs of the conversation back and forth, but there's no way to talk without typesetting.

Is there an equivalent of MathJaX for email?

Comment: Not really a math question.

Comment: Well, one variant is to send the TeX-code, and expect the other person to have soewhere they can paste it, but that's not much better than just sending a pdf.

Comment: I usually use (and I think it is not too uncommon) TeX-like syntax or in fact simplifications thereof working with spacing. E.g.: "For all  x in R, we have  sin x in [-1,1]."

Comment: You could send HTML formatted email and include a javascript library that applies [MathJAX](http://www.mathjax.org).

Comment: If you use gmail there is an addon called gmailtex.

Comment: @Xosdarap : I see nothing wrong with attaching PDF's to e-mails.

Comment: @lhf: True, but definitely of interest to mathematicians. I’d not encountered gmailtex before.

Comment: http://mathbin.net always used to be an option, but is apparently in the process of shutting down. (You may not like the lack of privacy or the necessity to open a browser tab (though I find this much less annoying than opening a PDF).)

Comment: @lhf: Not math, but math-related, therefore acceptable on Math.SE. Definitely useful for me, since I wasn't aware about GmailTeX.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I heartily recommend [gmailtex](http://alexeev.org/gmailtex.html). It's like mathjax for gmail. It installs as plugin to your browser. In any gmail account you have open, at a keystroke it processes all latex math environments and replaces them with either images or with HTML.

Sample screenshot:
[image]